# Let $G$ be a group and let $x$ be an element of $G$ such that $|x|=n$ . If there exists a number $m$ such that $x^m = 1$ then $n | m$.

Tags: group-theory

Here was my attempted proof, but my professor said it was no good. How should it be improved? Any "hints" for how I should proceed correctly?

Let $m$ be an integer such that $x^m = 1$. We know from our background assumptions, because $|x| = n$, that $x^n = 1$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
(x^n)^k = x^{kn} = 1 \, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}
By transitivity of equality,
\begin{align*}
    x^m = x^{kn}.
\end{align*}
Because of the cyclic structure of $x$, we know that this entails that
\begin{align*}
    m \in \{ kn : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}.
\end{align*}
Because this is the definition of modular congruence, we can deduce that
\begin{align*}
    m \equiv 0 \mod n.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
    m = kn \; \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor might be upset that you seem to be assuming at the beginning that $m = kn$ for some $k$. Here's one way to do it:

Since $n$ is the smallest number such that $x^n = 1$, we know $m \geq n$. Then write $m = qn +r$, where $ 0\leq r < n$.

This gives $x^{m}=x^{qn+r} = x^{r} = 1$. It follows that $r=0$.